# Is there any way to filter rows according multiple values in a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a tsv file like this.

| readId | V_segment |
| --- | --- |
| abc | IGHV3-18-F(2695) |
| def | IGHV3-9-F(2714),IGHV3-12-F(2656) |
| ghi | IGHV3-9-F(2840) |
| jkl | IGHV3-10-F(2666),IGHV3-18-F(2666) |

Using R, I need to filter, on the one hand, those rows containing a value in the column "V_segment" and on the other hand, those rows containing two or more values in the column "V_segment" (values separated by a comma). And create two tables: one with the rows with one value in "V_segment" column and other table with the rest of the rows.

The code I wrote until now is:

```
df <- read_tsv('alignments.tsv')
alignments_v <- data.frame(df$readId, df$V_segment,
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x <- alignments_v %>% separate(df.V_segment, c('V segment', 'Combinations V segment'), sep = ',')
```

But I'm not getting what I need...

I would need to get:

One table like this:

| readId | V_segment |
| --- | --- |
| abc | IGHV3-18-F(2695) |
| ghi | IGHV3-9-F(2840) |

and other table with the rows that have two values in the "V_segment" column:

| readId | V_segment |
| --- | --- |
| def | IGHV3-9-F(2714),IGHV3-12-F(2656) |
| jkl | IGHV3-10-F(2666),IGHV3-18-F(2666) |

Could you help me please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can use `grepl` to filter on the the comma separating multiple entries:

```
V_one <- df[!grepl(",", df$V_segment),]
#   readId        V_segment
# 1    abc IGHV3-18-F(2695)
# 3    ghi  IGHV3-9-F(2840)

V_twoplus <- df[grepl(",", df$V_segment),]
#   readId                         V_segment
# 2    def  IGHV3-9-F(2714),IGHV3-12-F(2656)
# 4    jkl IGHV3-10-F(2666),IGHV3-18-F(2666)
```

Comment: Oh, I did not know about grepl() function, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great! I am unclear on where you are getting the n values in your edit, but could edit my answer if you add a bit more explanation. Thanks!

Comment: I made another post with my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77846867/from-two-data-frames-is-there-any-way-to-count-unique-values-of-a-column-in-r . I would be so grateful if you could check it please, thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

We could `strsplit` the *V_segment* column then `split` by its `lengths`.

```
> split(td <- transform(dat, V_segment=strsplit(V_segment, ',')), lengths(td$V_segment))
$`1`
  readId        V_segment
1    abc IGHV3-18-F(2695)
3    ghi  IGHV3-9-F(2840)

$`2`
  readId                          V_segment
2    def  IGHV3-9-F(2714), IGHV3-12-F(2656)
4    jkl IGHV3-10-F(2666), IGHV3-18-F(2666)
```

Note that *V_segment* is then a list column.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(readId = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"), V_segment = c("IGHV3-18-F(2695)", 
"IGHV3-9-F(2714),IGHV3-12-F(2656)", "IGHV3-9-F(2840)", "IGHV3-10-F(2666),IGHV3-18-F(2666)"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```