# From two data frames, is there any way to count unique values of a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, count, unique, unique-values

From a tsv file, I have two tables.

For example,

table 1: V_one

| readId | V_segment |
| --- | --- |
| abc | IGHV3-18-F(2695) |
| ghi | IGHV3-9-F(2840) |

and

table 2: V_two

| readId | V_segment |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | IGHV3-9-F(2714),IGHV3-12-F(2656) |
| bbb | IGHV3-10-F(2666),IGHV3-18-F(2666) |

And I need to create another table where, for each unique value in the column "V_segment" of these new two tables, I get a count of the times every unique value appears in the column "V_segment" in the tsv file.

For example:

| V_segment | Count |
| --- | --- |
| IGHV3-18-F | 3 |
| IGHV3-9-F | 15 |
| IGHV3-9-F,IGHV3-12-F | 4 |
| IGHV3-10-F,IGHV3-18-F | 7 |

I tried this code:

```
df <- read_tsv('file.tsv') # tsv file with lots of columns
segmV <- data.frame(df$readId, df$V_segment, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # create a data frame with two columns of the tsv file
V_one <- segmV[!grepl(",", df$V_segment),] # table 1
V_two <- segmV[grepl(",", df$V_segment),] # table 2

v1 <- V_one %>%
      group_by(V_one$V_segment) %>%
      mutate(Count = n_distinct(V_one$V_segment))
```

But it's not working, since (for this) I need to ignore the information in the parenthesis.

```
> dput(head(V_one, n=10))
structure(list(readId = c("abc", "def", 
"ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwy", "zab", "cde"), 
    V_segment = c("IGHV3-18-F(2695)", "IGHV3-18-F(2782)", 
    "IGHV3-18-F(2772)", "IGHV3-18-F(1952)", "IGHV3-15-F(2792)", 
    "IGHV3-18-F(2558)", "IGHV3-9-F(2831)", "IGHV3-18-F(2221)", 
    "IGHV3-18-F(2812)", "IGHV3-15-F(2791)")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 19L, 24L, 25L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(V_two, n=10))
structure(list(readId = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", 
"ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj"), 
    V_segment = c("IGHV3-10-F(2429),IGHV3-12-F(2429)", 
    "IGHV3-9-F(2714),IGHV3-12-F(2656)", "IGHV1-16-ORF(2920),IGHV1-19-F(2920)", 
    "IGHV3-17-F(2512),IGHV3-18-F(2512)", "IGHV3-10-F(2666),IGHV3-18-F(2666)", 
    "IGHV1-8-F(2901),IGHV1-21-F(2814)", "IGHV3-10-F(2685),IGHV3-18-F(2685)", 
    "IGHV3-12-F(2801),IGHV3-20-F(2743)", "IGHV3-20-F(2754),IGHV3-10-F(2725)", 
    "IGHV3-10-F(2714),IGHV3-18-F(2714)")), row.names = c(3L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(V_table3, n=10))
structure(list(readId = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", 
 "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj"), 
        V_segment = c("IGHV3-10-F(242,9),IGHV3-12-F(242,9)", 
        "IGHV3-9-F(271,4),IGHV3-12-F(265,6)", "IGHV1-16-ORF(292,0),IGHV1-19-F(2920)", 
        "IGHV3-17-F(251,2),IGHV3-18-F(2512)", "IGHV3-10-F(2666),IGHV3-18-F(2666)", 
        "IGHV1-8-F(290,1),IGHV1-21-F(281,4)", "IGHV3-10-F(2685),IGHV3-18-F(2685)", 
        "IGHV3-12-F(2801),IGHV3-20-F(274,3)", "IGHV3-20-F(2754),IGHV3-10-F(272,5)", 
        "IGHV3-10-F(2714),IGHV3-18-F(271,4)")), row.names = c(3L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Could you help me please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `df`? Why are you referencing it in your `mutate` when it seems you should be using the variable from `V_one`? I suggest something as simple as `bind_rows(V_one, V_two) %>% count(V_segment)`.

Comment: Hello, sorry, it was an error

Comment: Okay, then ... (almost) never reference `V_one$` in a pipe started on `V_one`; while there are some uncommon times when it makes sense, the rest of the time it is _at best_ inefficient, often causing either errors (not horrible, at least you know) or silently giving your incorrect results (very bad). Does my code suggestion work for you?

Comment: Hi, sorry for replying so late. Your code works but the problem is that I need to ignore the info in brackets. For example, for the combinations: IGHV1-11-P(1005),IGHV1-21-F(1005) & IGHV1-11-P(1028),IGHV1-21-F(1028), I need to be counted as a single combination, and your code counts as two different combinations (probably because of the info in brackets). Thank you advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "V_"))) %>%  
  count(V_segment)

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  V_segment                             n
  <chr>                             <int>
1 IGHV3-10-F(2666),IGHV3-18-F(2666)     1
2 IGHV3-18-F(2695)                      1
3 IGHV3-9-F(2714),IGHV3-12-F(2656)      1
4 IGHV3-9-F(2840)                       1
```

Individual segments:

```
bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "V_"))) %>% 
  mutate(across(V_segment, ~ str_remove_all(.x, "\\(.*?\\)"))) %>%  
  count(V_segment)

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  V_segment                 n
  <chr>                 <int>
1 IGHV3-10-F,IGHV3-18-F     1
2 IGHV3-18-F                1
3 IGHV3-9-F                 1
4 IGHV3-9-F,IGHV3-12-F      1
```

With the provided sample data:

```
V_one <- structure(list(readId = c("abc", "def", 
                          "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwy", "zab", "cde"), 
               V_Segment = c("IGHV3-18-F(2695)", "IGHV3-18-F(2782)", 
                             "IGHV3-18-F(2772)", "IGHV3-18-F(1952)", "IGHV3-15-F(2792)", 
                             "IGHV3-18-F(2558)", "IGHV3-9-F(2831)", "IGHV3-18-F(2221)", 
                             "IGHV3-18-F(2812)", "IGHV3-15-F(2791)")), row.names = c(1L, 
                                                                                     2L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 19L, 24L, 25L), class = "data.frame") %>% 
  as_tibble()

V_one %>%  
  mutate(V_Segment = str_remove(V_Segment, "\\(.*?\\)")) %>%
  count(V_Segment)

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  V_Segment      n
  <chr>      <int>
1 IGHV3-15-F     2
2 IGHV3-18-F     7
3 IGHV3-9-F      1
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. My problem is that I need you to ignore the information in brackets when counting. Sorry if I'm not explaining well.. It would be great if I could delete that information before starting to count

Comment: @Silvia Take a look at my edits now - would that work? Or do you need the segments in commas?

Comment: I need that in table two, where there are two values for each readId, each unique combination is counted as one (i.e. do not separate the segments in these combinations, count each unique combination as one) please. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Silvia Like this?

Comment: Hoel, why are you using `mget` and `across` here? They seem to add unneeded complexity. Also, make sure to mention `library(stringr)`, or just switch to `gsub`. I'd think this may be simpler with `bind_rows(V_one, V_two) %>% mutate(V_segment = str_remove_all(V_segment, "\\(.*?\\)"))`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for replying late, I'm getting errors with your codes. I just updated the code I used to create the tables.. maybe it's because of a syntax error of mine or something... Could you check it please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: "I'm getting errors" if not helpful, what errors do you get? This code works given your sample data.

Comment: Hi, it worked with both codes, thank you so much!! I was my mistake because I didn't add this part to your code `%>% count(V_segment) `, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error: `Error in if (length == 1) return(alphabet) else kronecker(alphabet, words(length -  : 
  the condition has length > 1` after running: `count_table_Vone <- V_one %>%
  mutate(V_segment = str_remove_all(V_Segment, "\\(.*?\\)")) %>%
  count(V_Segment)` Could you help me please? Thank you!

Comment: @Silvia Please update the question with `dput(head(V_one, n = 10))`

Comment: Be sure to be choose the correct col name, see that you have used both V_Segment and V_segment. Updated my answer

Comment: Hi, it worked, thank you so much! How could I do it with the other table (V_two)? (I just updated my question with `dput(head(V_two, n = 10))`). I just changed `str_remove` for `str_remove_all` and it looks like it worked, could you confirm it please? Thank you!

Comment: @Silvia `V_two %>%  
  separate_rows(V_segment, sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(V_segment = str_remove(V_segment, "\\(.*?\\)")) %>%
  count(V_segment)`

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the [answer given by @BigFinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77849113/20002111) with a few modifications:
**(1)** Copy and paste colnames from `V_one` to `V_two`, since there is a difference: `V_Segment` and `V_segment`.
**(2)** Create a new object `V`. This allows us to have a look at it if we like to.
**(3)** Convert the `table` to `data.frame` and set names.

Based on your desired output I would recommend to do:

```r
names(V_two) = names(V_one)
V = rbind(V_one, V_two)
V$V_Segment = gsub("\\([0-9]+\\)", "", V$V_Segment)
as.data.frame(table(V$V_Segment)) |> setNames(c("V_Segment", "Count"))
```

which gives

```r
                 V_Segment Count
1  IGHV1-16-ORF,IGHV1-19-F     1
2     IGHV1-8-F,IGHV1-21-F     1
3    IGHV3-10-F,IGHV3-12-F     1
4    IGHV3-10-F,IGHV3-18-F     3
5    IGHV3-12-F,IGHV3-20-F     1
6               IGHV3-15-F     2
7    IGHV3-17-F,IGHV3-18-F     1
8               IGHV3-18-F     7
9    IGHV3-20-F,IGHV3-10-F     1
10               IGHV3-9-F     1
11    IGHV3-9-F,IGHV3-12-F     1
```

---

Data:

```r
V_one = structure(list(readId = c("abc", "def", 
                                  "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwy", "zab", "cde"), 
                       V_Segment = c("IGHV3-18-F(2695)", "IGHV3-18-F(2782)", 
                                     "IGHV3-18-F(2772)", "IGHV3-18-F(1952)", "IGHV3-15-F(2792)", 
                                     "IGHV3-18-F(2558)", "IGHV3-9-F(2831)", "IGHV3-18-F(2221)", 
                                     "IGHV3-18-F(2812)", "IGHV3-15-F(2791)")), 
                  row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 17L, 19L, 24L, 25L), class = "data.frame") 

V_two = structure(list(readId = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", 
                          "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj"), 
               V_segment = c("IGHV3-10-F(2429),IGHV3-12-F(2429)", 
                             "IGHV3-9-F(2714),IGHV3-12-F(2656)", "IGHV1-16-ORF(2920),IGHV1-19-F(2920)", 
                             "IGHV3-17-F(2512),IGHV3-18-F(2512)", "IGHV3-10-F(2666),IGHV3-18-F(2666)", 
                             "IGHV1-8-F(2901),IGHV1-21-F(2814)", "IGHV3-10-F(2685),IGHV3-18-F(2685)", 
                             "IGHV3-12-F(2801),IGHV3-20-F(2743)", "IGHV3-20-F(2754),IGHV3-10-F(2725)", 
                             "IGHV3-10-F(2714),IGHV3-18-F(2714)")), 
               row.names = c(3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! The columns name is `V_segment`. `V_Segment` was a mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution:

```
V_one = data.frame(
    readId = c("abc", "ghi"),
    V_segment = c("IGHV3-18-F(2695)", "IGHV3-9-F(2840)")
)

V_two = data.frame(
    readId = c("def", "jkl"),
    V_segment = c("IGHV3-9-F(2714),IGHV3-12-F(2656)", "IGHV3-10-F(2666),IGHV3-18-F(2666)")
)

table(gsub("\\([0-9]+\\)","",rbind(V_one,V_two)$V_segment))
```

Result:

```
IGHV3-10-F,IGHV3-18-F            IGHV3-18-F             IGHV3-9-F  IGHV3-9-F,IGHV3-12-F 
                    1                     1                     1                     1
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I'm getting this error: `< table of extent 0 >` I just edited the code I used to create the tables.. Thank you in advance!